# Setting tcp ip argument while booting up linux

Tags: linux, embedded-linux

Could somebody explain me how to set the tcp ip parameter while linux boots up in my board.

Currently i am giving it like : **tcp ip=:::::eth0:dhcp**

If i have my own static ip and its corresponding mac-id can i change it for my board when i boot up.

Please help with valuable pointers.

Thanks,
Sen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?
HowToGeek: [Change Ubuntu Server from DHCP to a Static IP Address](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/change-ubuntu-server-from-dhcp-to-a-static-ip-address/)

You'd need to edit /etc/network/interfaces to set a static IP, it would look something like this

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.100
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
```

You'd also want to add dns settings to `/etc/resolv.conf` and remove the dhcp client for this to stick.